# object is not save,delete or update in database without any error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I am using spring 3 with hibernate 3.1 integeration in myeclipse. The problem is that "student" instance is not saved, updated, or deleted in the database without error or exception, but other functions like findbyid and all works correctly.

Here is my `applicationcontext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">


    <bean id="hibernateSession"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation"
            value="file:src/hibernate.cfg.xml">
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="StudentDAO"
        class="com.myeclipse.hibernatespring.StudentDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="hibernateSession" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="persistenceLayer"
        class="com.myeclipse.hibernatespring.PersistenceLayer"
        abstract="false" lazy-init="default" autowire="default"
        p:studentDAO-ref="StudentDAO">
    </bean></beans>
```

My `persistenceLayer` class:

```
package com.myeclipse.hibernatespring;

public class PersistenceLayer {
    private StudentDAO studentDAO;

    public StudentDAO getStudentDAO() {
        return studentDAO;
    }

    public void setStudentDAO(StudentDAO studentDAO) {
        this.studentDAO = studentDAO;
    }
    public void addStudent(Student st){
        studentDAO.save(st);
    }
    public Student findStudentById(Integer id){
        return studentDAO.findById(id);
    }
}
```

My `buisnesslogic` class:

```
package com.myeclipse.hibernatespring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class BuisnessLogic {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Student stu=new Student(4,"gaurav",67.7f);
        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
                PersistenceLayer pl=(PersistenceLayer) ctx.getBean("persistenceLayer");
                pl.addStudent(stu);
                Student st=pl.findStudentById(2);
                System.out.print(st.getName());
    }

}
```

My hibernate.cfg:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.                   -->
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="myeclipse.connection.profile">
            MySQL Connector/J
        </property>
        <mapping
            resource="com/myeclipse/hibernatespring/Student.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: probably, because your transaction is not commited, post hibernate config, or try flush() method on hibernate session..

Comment: you are not saving you are retrieving, but i think that to save or update youy have to use @Transactional annotation or something like that in your service layer ..

Comment: ok here it is my hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your transactions. The simplest way, is to use annotation-driven transactions and `@Transactional` annotation. Have a look at [this](http://simplespringtutorial.com/springDeclarativeTransactions.html) tutorial.